# iText 7 - PDF restriction changed after output

Tags: c#, itext

I have a fillable pdf form that I am trying to fill out. I am using the SetUnethicalReading(True) for PdfReader.

But after I fill in the form, it seem like the form is no longer editable. If I were to do this manually, the form is editable.
Is there a way around this?

Comment: Have you used the append mode for filling in?